# Rhythmbox CD "extract" button doesn't appear

Tags: rhythmbox, cd, extract

When I load a CD (Steely Dan) into my drive, I can play it just fine. Unfortunately the "extract" button doesn't appear so I can't extract it into the computer.
If I put a different CD (Il Divo) into the drive then "extract" is available as usual.

Feel free to comment on the music content as you like.  :)

Comment: Okay, sorry I didn't provide the OS & release date - I thought that with the information provided then the question would be obvious: If I the "extract" button doesn't appear then there must be a problem... any ideas what the problem and solution would be? I would like to be able to extract CDs into my computer, comprende?  My OS is Ubuntu 20.04, I don't know which date I installed it and don't know how to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the separate tracks of an audio CD you can copy the songs that are shown in Files to your filesystem where they will show up as .wav files. This works for almost all audio CDs except for two exceptions.

1. Some CDs (a very small percentage of  them) have copyright copy prevention encoded into the CD that makes it impossible to copy the CD to a computer or computer-attached storage device.
2. Damaged tracks containing scratches can sometimes be copied, but if the CD is too damaged the damaged tracks cannot be copied, and the same goes for the CD if the whole CD is damaged.

After the CD has been copied the resulting .wav can be played as is or converted into other audio formats. I haven't found any software for Ubuntu that can edit .wav files and save them in the original .wav format, but Audacity can edit every audio file format that I've tried and save in it in its original file format except for .wav files.

Comment: Thank you karel, I appreciate your ideas. I'll give this a try. fivecook